# Why Firebase cloud messaging push notification token encounter an UNREGISTERED (HTTP 404)?

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using a PWA for my application and I get a token using the method getToken and then attempt to send a notification to that token using the "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" API, but I encounter an UNREGISTERED (HTTP 404) problem. Again when I try to fetch the token, it gets the same token. This means that the token I am using is a valid one. But while sending the notification using the same token, I get the message UNREGISTERED.

**CURL used to send a notification**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
--header 'Authorization: key=<SERVER_KEY>
--data-raw '{
"registration_ids": [
"<FIREBASE_USER_TOKEN>"
],
"notification": {
"title": "<,TITLE_OF_NOTIFICATION>"
"body": "<BODY_MESSAGE_OF_NOTIFICATION>"
}
}'
```

**We have write a javascript code to get a token from the firebase**

```
const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
if (permission === 'granted') {
const token = await getToken(messaging, {
vapidKey: process.env.VAPID_KEY,
});
}
```

**And use firebase-messaging-sw.js for get a notification**

```
 importScripts(
    'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js',
);
importScripts(
    'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js',
);
firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.onBackgroundMessage(payload => {
        const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
        const notificationOptions = {
            body: payload.data.body,
            icon: payload.data.icon,
            badge: payload.data.badge,
            click_action:payload.data.click_action,
        };
        self.registration.showNotification(
            notificationTitle,
            notificationOptions,
        );
```

Please help me to solve this problem.